# Ansible: use both lists and their contents as variable values

Tags: loops, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have key - value pairs association in the form of:

```
- mykey1:
    myvalues1: ['a', 'b', 'c']
- mykey2:
    myvalues2: ['d', 'e']
- mykey3:
    myvalues3: ['f']
```

I know that using the `with_dict` construct I can iterate over both keys and  values (which are lists).
My question is how can I have a loop that iterates over the **list's (values) elements**?

The output i would like to be able to achieve is:

```
a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
```

The problem is that I need to maintain the above associations.
Is there a way to avoid duplicating list declarations?

Comment: `['a', 'b', 'c']` in your declaration is a list object. What is `'a', 'b', 'c'` in your wanted output? A string?

Comment: Three distinct string objects.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have problems imaging how you could store three distinct objects in a single value.

Comment: @techraf you were right I had not formulated correctly my expected output. It is has been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the construct I came up with:

```
associations:    
    - { key: mykey1, myvalues: ['a', 'b', 'c', ] }
    - { key: mykey2, myvalues: ['d', 'e'] }
    - { key: mykey3, myvalues: ['f'] }
```

When someone wants to iterate over values as **single values**

```
- name: List single items
  debug:
     msg: "{{ item.1 }}"
   with_subelements:
     - associations
     - myvalues
```

When someone wants to iterate over values **as lists**

```
- name: List lists (no pun intended)
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.myvalues }}"
  with_items: associations
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if it is possible with dynamic keys. But assuming the following vars file without the 1,2 and 3:

```
rootitem:
  - mykey:
      myvalues: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  - mykey:
      myvalues: ['d', 'e']
  - mykey:
      myvalues: ['f']
```

It is possible using "with_subelements" with the following example:

```
- name: iterate over list
  debug:
    msg: "the current item is{{ item.0 }} and all subitems are {{ item.1 }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ rootitem }}"
    - mykey.myvalues
```

This results in 6 iterations one for each of "a,b,c,d,e,f".

Comment: This actually iterates over keys (i.e. it will print `mykey1`, `mykey2`, `mykey3`)

Comment: Editted my solution and should work if you don't depend on dynamically changing keys.

Comment: It works I came up with sth similar at the same time. Thanks for the feedback, one upvote from me.